# Naming a list with the string value of an int

Tags: python, list

How can I name a list with the string value of an int?
Example pseudo-code:

```
int i = 4;
list + i = [] // i want the name of the list to be thus 'list4'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't declare type of variables in python, so `i = 4` works just fine, also word "list" is reserved in python, so try to not use words which may collide with python built-ins. If you realy need to do that (which i don't recommend), you can achieve it by usin `eval()`

Comment: `eval('list' + str(i)) = []` gives can't assign to function call...